# Use gaction to change a Smarthome Action fulfilment URL

Tags: google-smart-home

I want to be able to update/change the fulfilment URL of a Smart Home action using the gactions cli tool. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please put a clear description and technical details like which `Smart solution` you are intended to using ?

Comment: No you are expected to just put a single fulfillment URL in the console.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer.

Comment: I am trying to automate an end to end deployment of a google smart home action with an API (in this case AWS API Gateway), and want to be able to point google home to the new api end point, as it could have a new API ID, and hence a new URL. I can overcome this by having a common DNS name to point to it. Not having a command line option is a disappointment.

Comment: @RatulSharker, I am trying to use Google Smart home

Answer (score 0):

No you are expected to just put a single fulfillment URL in the console and save it.